# sshd "received disconnect: disconnected by user"

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sftp, chroot

I can successfully login to the SFTP server *(uses SFTP chrooting)*, but every time I issue `ls`, the connection will close:

- I mounted `/logs/xxx` to `/sftp/user/xxx` and am unsure if the binding I did has something to with this - server's `/var/log/secure`:

  ```
  15:39:49 sftp_server sshd[12574]:         Postponed publickey for sftp_user from x.x.x.x port 48598 ssh2
  15:39:49 sftp_server sshd[12573]:         Found matching RSA key: ed:30:22:54:ef:39:c7:3b:2b:6e:d4:5a:b0:78:5d:b7
  15:39:56 sftp_server pam_cyberark[12573]: [cd082fe8-7c4a-4b4a-9b81-545ea00f1532] pam_sm_acct_mgmt: Failure for user [sftp_user]
  15:39:56 sftp_server sshd[12573]:         Accepted publickey for sftp_user from x.x.x.x port 48598 ssh2
  15:39:56 sftp_server sshd[12573]:         pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftp_user by (uid=0)
  15:39:57 sftp_server sshd[12573]:         User child is on pid 12876
  15:39:57 sftp_server sshd[12876]:         Changed root directory to "/sftp/sftp_user"
  15:39:57 sftp_server sshd[12876]:         subsystem request for sftp
  15:40:39 sftp_server sshd[12876]:         Received disconnect from x.x.x.x: 11: disconnected by user
  15:40:39 sftp_server sshd[12573]:         pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftp_user
  ```
- I have a similar set up on a VM working perfectly that replicates the same configuration *(ownership, permission, binding, `sshd_config`, etc.)*